# Knife ec2 Create

Tags: chef, knife

I am successfully running chef server and able to bootstrap server with my chef recipes.

I would like to know is there any plugin which we can use to launch multiple servers using

knife ec2 create command.?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a look at [Spiceweasel](https://github.com/mattray/spiceweasel).  It does many more things that server creation, but you can ignore the rest of it if that's all you need.